CausalImpact package in R - One-tailed probability
This is my first time using Bayesian statistics and the CausalImpact package in R. I'm a bit confused about whether this is using one-tail or two-tailed probability testing and was wondering if anyone knows the answer? The verbose option of the summary output suggests that it is one-tailed. I am trying to test whether there has been a change in any direction (positive or negative) following an intervention rather than having a specific direction in mind. Is this still a suitable method to be using?
Thanks in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/415087/7071
